# I need to know how the output was generated by this source code

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char c[]="GATE2016";
    char *p = c;
    printf("%s",p+ p[3] - p[1]);
}
```

The output to the above source code is

```
2016
```

I don't have the slightest clue how that came. Also when I edit

```
char c[]="asdf2016"
```

the output shown is

```
`
```

Can anybody help me in this?

Comment: The output is implementation-defined, since not all C-implementations use ASCII.

Comment: explain more..I want to know the cause of output.

Comment: `p[3] = 'E'`, `p[1] = 'A'`, `'E' - 'A' = 4`, `p+4 = "2016"`.

Comment: then why output changed when i wrote     char c[]="asdf2016"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `p` is a pointer to the first element of the array `c`, so whenever you pass `p` alone it is going to behave exactly the same way as if you passed `c`, that is it will read from the adress of `p` until it reaches the string terminator `'\0'` .

Now, some say that it depends on whether your code uses ASCII or EBCDIC or any other encoding. While it's not wrong, your code does not depend immediatly on this. What matters is that, in the case of your string `"GATE2016"` the characters `'A'` and `'E'`(which are the ones accessed in this bizarre-looking code in the printf call) come one after the other and that substracting A from E gives 4, you'll see why. For the sake of this example, I'll use ASCII.

In ASCII, the characters `'A'` equals 65, and `'E'` equals 69. So in the line

```
printf("%s",p+ p[3] - p[1]);
```

what you are actually doing can be translated as

```
printf("%s",p+ 'E' - 'A');
```

or simply

```
printf("%s",p+ 69 - 65);
```

which can be further simplified as

```
printf("%s",p + 4);
```

Now since the `"%s"` format of printf expects a pointer to the beginning of a string, what you are actually passing as an argument in this case is the address of `p` + 4 (which since it's a pointer, gets shifted by 4 memory slots), so you end up with position [4] as the beginning of the string (`p + 4 == &p[4]`), printf starts reading your string at position 4, which contains the 2 of 2016. From there it just reads until it reaches `'\0'` in you string and just prints out 2016, which also explains why it does not work with `"asdf"`.

Just remember that characters in C are simply numbers, and that, in ASCII, writing `'A'` is exactly the same as writing the number `65`.

Comment: when why output is
'`'
when i use 
'char c[]="asdf2016'    ?

Comment: when why output is ' ` ' when i use ' char c[]="asdf2016 ' ?

Comment: Be cause then you're subtracting `'s'` (=115) from `'f'` (= 102), which results equals -13, so you're trying to access something out of the array, which as far as I know is undefined behaviour so it could print anything.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

First of all variable p is an address, as well as c. Second of all, characters are still represented as numbers internally. I assume that in your implementation the ASCII code dictates what that representation is, so in ASCII:

> 'E' = 69 and  'A'=65 ,
>   for more see [ascii code](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif)

```
p[3] = 'E' 
p[1] = 'A'
```

in your string and so that printf actually prints from p+4 meaning from p[4] till the end.

Comment: There is no requirement in C for the implementation to use ASCII, rather than, say, EBCDIC.

Comment: then why output changed when i wrote

Comment: Then why output changed when i wrote char c[]="asdf2016"

Comment: Because if you look at f-s it will be a negative number and the output will be undefined seeing that it goes outside of the array

Comment: whats f-s ? Explain more sir...the output is still undefined to me.

Comment: If you put "asdf2016" then p[3] will be 'f' and p[1] will be 's' , and so if you look at the ASCII code you will see that 's'>'f' and you will have p-something which is an address outside of your c[] array